Being strict or kind about "newbie" questions?
Recently a few newbie questions popped up on the SE, like this one. Seeing them one knows that they were already asked before a couple times. My question is - should we be strict or kind about such newbie questions? That is to say, should we answer the question before closing it down and referring the user to relevant sources, or just do the latter without providing an answer to the question? The first approach might help the user asking the question with their problem faster, while the second would teach them that they should search before asking a question.
Which approach should we try to apply in most cases as a community?

This person obviously didn't read the instructions.
Close the question and direct the poster to the FAQ. 
If there was only one issue (e.g. multiple questions in a single post) mention it to the OP.
By no way you should start a discussion. This would be encouragement for others to do the same.
